# Collecting touch points

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

As far as I know, there's no public API to collect touch points/locations at a sample rate. Does anyone know of any workaround to accomplish this? Thanks so much in advance for any thought and advice.

Comment: An API **DOES** exist to collect every single touch that occurs. You can use `-(void)touchesBegan`, `-(void)touchesMoved` and `-(void)touchesEnded` to know all you need. What more are you looking for?

Comment: I meant "at a sample rate", not just collecting touch points. How do I collect them at a given sample rate?

Comment: I get what you said, but you get ***all*** of them ***as they happen***. If they're not moving, why would you want to continue sampling them? If they ***are*** moving, you're notified, and you can take a timestamp at that time. I still don't understand what you're after that the `UITouch` class doesn't provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't [UITouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) be what you're looking for?

Comment: I am aware of UITouch and the methods touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded. However, what I want to accomplish here is to collect the touch points at a specific sampling rate.

Comment: When you register a touch, check the NSDate and figure out from there whether it's within range of your sample rate. I think setting up a timer is overkill, since it's running regardless of whether the user touches or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSTimer:

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/TIMES_PER_SECOND target:self selector:@selector(sampleTouches:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Then, implement the callback function:

```
-(void)sampleTouches:(NSTimer*)timer {
    // Call a method/function here that gets UITouch data.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! As far as I understand, I need to access the UIEvent object that handle the touch event in this callback function. How do I relate the touch event with this callback? Do I still need to implement - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Comment: 2 things: 1) His `NSTimer` object is set up incorrectly. You want `1.0 / TIMES_PER_SECOND`. 2) Simply setting up an `NSTimer` doesn't give you any extra access to `UITouch` objects. You really want to handle the `UITouch` events. This way isn't a good solution.

Comment: @mbm30075 1) You are absolutely correct. I usually just implement them to run once per second, so I simply use 1.0 there. Sorry for the mix-up. 2) That's why I put the comment there explaining to write a separate method to grab the current UITouch status. I think that what needs to be answered is what HappyAppDeveloper is trying to do, specifically, that requires poling for touches at a specified interval.

Comment: To mbm30075: Let me rephrase your 2nd statement so that I can make sure that I understand this correctly (and please correct me if I'm wrong): Even if I set up an NSTimer object with a really large number for TIMES_PER_SECOND and was able to collect more touch points, the extra points collected (compared to what I can get through touchesBegan touchesMoved etc) are just duplicate of previous points. The points that I can get from the method touchesBegan touchMoved etc are the maximum and most accurate that I can possibly get, aren't they?

Comment: As far as I know, these methods are the most accurate values that can be obtained using documented APIs. Another possibility is to just use the touches* events and compare timestamps to see whether or not to act upon these touches. The touch sampling rate on iOS is approximately 60hz (60 times per second), so if you want to only scan them 30 times per second, you could increment a counter each time, and `if(counter % 2)` run your code.

Comment: @C0deH4cker Let me be clear: I'm not picking on your solution. You ***did*** answer the question as asked. I usually try to do that, because I assume the OP knows what they're doing. In this case, though, there is **literally** nothing to be gained with this particular methodology. I just wanted to make it clear to him that the normal way to handle touches is actually the best.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that recording touch points at a sample rate does not make the recording any faster or more accurate. The touch methods were the way to go. By implementing the methods touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnd, I was able to record the touch points which were given to the view as they happen and as fast as they possibly will.